# Pass a data member of an object of the same class by reference while using const C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, reference, constants

I will try to demonstrate the concept of what I was working on and resulted a compile-time error:

Assume the following:

```
class Parent
{
     //SOME CODE
};

class Child : public class Parent
{
   private:
     Parent * p_obj;

   public:
     void function_1(const Child & c)
     {
        function_2(c.p_obj); //pass p_obj by reference from an instance of the same class
     }

     void function_2(const Parent *& ptr)
     {
        //here I want to use ptr as a pointer to copy its data, but will not modify it.
        //since I am not modifying it, I wanted  to pass it by reference to avoid wasting memory and run-time performance  
        //however, I get an error. MOST likely caused by the const keyword
     }    
};
```

The error I get is something like that:

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Parent *const' to
'const Parent *&' for 1st argument int function_2(const Parent *&);
```

Comment: You can't pass a reference to `T*` when the caller wants a reference to `const T*`.

Comment: What T? @MartinBonner

Comment: This is not a duplicate and the other question was not marked as the correct answer! @MartinBonner

Comment: `Parent *const` is a const pointer to a mutable Parent.  `const Parent *&` is a reference of a mutable pointer to const Parent.  They're not interchangeable.

Comment: @cccds : `T` is the type being pointed to.  In your case `T` is `Parent`.  In the linked question `T` is `uint8_t`.  Your problem has nothing to do with `p_obj` being a data member.  Your problem is that `p_obj` is `Parent *`, which is *not* the same as `Parent const *`.

Comment: The fact that the OP of the linked question didn't understand the provided answer well enough to accept it, does not mean the provided answer is wrong (it isn't).  I'm happy to edit the duplicate notice if you can provide better duplicates (there almost certainly are several)

Comment: If I changed `const Parent *&` to `Parent *const` would this mean that the data member of the passed class would be copied in a different address? Although I already passed the object of the entire class by reference (of which this data member is part of), and used a pass by value for that data member in function_2. @Eljay

Comment: @cccds : The data member would indeed be copied to a different address - but note that the data member is not a `Parent`, it is just a pointer telling the program where to find a `Parent`.  If `function_2` does not attempt to change what the pointer is pointing to, then you should pass pointers by value.

Comment: How would you go about fixing `Parent *` to `Parent const *` in this case? Would adding a local `Parent const temp_var;` be valid? @MartinBonner

Comment: I'd fix it by doing `void function_1(Child const& c) {...}` and `void function_2(Parent const& ptr) {...}`.

Comment: If data member is not the `Parent` then what pass by value `*` copy in this case to a different address? Would it only copy the address of `Parent`? Or would it copy the contents of that `Parent` address?

Comment: I tried your fix, but it results an error! @MartinBonner

Comment: A Child instance IS-A Parent instance.  Why does the Child instance need to have a Parent* member variable?  Is that member variable set in the Child constructor?  Is `function_2` being used to set that member variable?  There are some unknowns here, which make it hard to offer advice.

Comment: Because the Child is a list where the Parent* member is a pointer to its head node. function_2 copies the contents of the node (Parent) @Eljay

Comment: So if you need to pass a pointer to Child, then pass a pointer to it, not a reference:  `void function_2(Parent*)`